# ActiveModel::Serializer: convert ids to strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

When I serialize a model object to JSON I want to convert all IDs to strings, because they should be "back box" values in JavaScript, and not double precision floating point numbers. Is there a way to tell `ActiveModel::Serializer` to run all IDs through `.to_s` (if not nil)?

I already tried to make a `BaseSerializer` class that defines a custom `id` method from which all other serializers inherit. This method does the appropriate conversion to string but it is not called for e.g. `belongs_to` relation where only the IDs are rendered (because of JSON nesting depths cutoff).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this....

I have a serializer like that

```
class ResumesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :first_name, :last_name, :age

  def age
    object.talent.age.to_s if object.talent.age.present? 
  end
end
```

Comment: So I have to do this for every relation I have in our app everywhere? Also this will always emit the age, even if the nesting depths usually would cause to omit it.

Comment: Yes you need to do this for only customize attribute.